# Read NumPy 4d int array from python to C#

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a 4d 61x41x61x41 numpy integer array in python which I want to read in Unity. Which is the best way to do it and with what data format should I work with?

I have tried with JSON but JSONUtility has trouble reading it as it is not an object. What would you suggest?

EDIT: When using JSON I tried this:

```
class TransitionClass
    {
        public List<List<List<List<int>>>> transitionMatrices = new List<List<List<List<int>>>>();
    }

TransitionClass transition;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(transitionJsonPath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            transition = JsonUtility.FromJson<TransitionClass>(json);
        }
```

But I get an empty list returned.

The JSON file right now looks like this:

```
{"transitionMatrices":[[[[8,3,12,0,2,0,0,5 ... 2,4,1,0]]]]}
```

I even tried using simple arrays and without using classes but got the error 'JSON must represent an object type'

Comment: then try [xmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0), or show your attemp for the potential helper to be able to help out

Comment: Rather ruse the [Newtonsoft .NET JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html?_ga=2.165682238.1438676683.1610207839-1503811403.1600323997)(via package Manager) or [via this asset](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity) which is way more powerful than the built-in JsonUtility

Comment: I edited the post to display code. Does this work for Unity too?

Comment: if you change `transitionMatrices` type to int[][][][] does it work?

Comment: You mean int[,,,]? I did that and still the same..

Answer (score 0):

If you change `transitionMatrices` to be an `int [][][][]` it works with the built in JsonSerializer in c#

```
        public void JsonTest()
        {
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TransitionClass>(@"{""transitionMatrices"":[[[[8,3,12,0,2,0,0,5,4,1,0]]]]}");
        }

        public class TransitionClass
        {
            public int [][][][] transitionMatrices { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: So I should use JsonSerializer but when I type it I get:
The name 'JsonSerializer' does not exist in the current context. Is it part of the Newtonsoft .NET JSON package?

Comment: @VaggelisStamkopoulos Sorry its a nugget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/